# GSM system description

Tags: gsm

We want to launch a vehicle tracking service, remote monitoring of assets through GPRS/SMS. development, integration and maintenance of gps tracking software /Remote Monitoring SYSTem (Gsm/Gprs based)having Google Map API or mapinfo,.img or possibility to integrate any other map service, geo fencing, geo-coding, reverse geo-coding, alerts on events, user friendly gui, dash board, Billing each user , scrolling, fuel meter display etc. For reference , have a look at gpsgate.com (tracking server solution)

How to develop this and how much time is needed for this ?, any idea ?

Comment: I want to develop this kind of system in .net

Answer (score 1):

First of all you will need some sort of gateway. It must handle TCP connections from devices(use async sockets!=)), parse their data and send to storage.

Next big thing is storage itself. If you want to support different devices, I would suggest to use something like Apache Cassandra with keys, based on date(only date, not time)and device UID.

Third part of puzzle is how you going to present data to users. This is pretty simple. Id suggest REST services.

This is my own experience. On my last job I was an Architect/Lead on quite the same project.
It is now live and successful handling 30k+ devices online on 1 server for apps(IIS), 2 for data and 2 for TCP gateways.

If you want more specific info, feel free to ask=)

Comment: don't forget to vote for useful comments and mark most helpful ones as answers=)

Comment: @AlexeyAnufriyev, how to track vehicles using GSM. is it possible? if so, what kind of services or technologies can be used?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, it all depends on your skills and expertise.

A team that is well versed in designing complex systems like that could finish the task in 4-6 months.

Given that you are asking such a question, rather than already having a ballpark estimate, means that you probably would be learning as you go. This could easily stretch into over a year, especially without prior experience managing such an overarching project.